# Apache Camel runs part of onCompletion and doesn't show stack trace

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm trying to use a Camel poll-once route that will use a file if it's present and log an error if not.

By default the route does nothing if the file does not exist so I've started by adding `consumer.sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle=true` to the URI. I then check for null body to decide whether to log an exception or continue:

```
    from(theFileUri)
        .onCompletion()
            .onCompleteOnly()
            .log("SUCCESS")
            .bean(theOtherAction, "start")
        .end()
        .onException(Exception.class)
            .logStackTrace(true)
            .log(ERROR, "Failed to load file")
            .handled(true)
        .end()
        .choice()
            .when(body().isNotNull())
                .to(NEXT_ROUTE_URI)
            .endChoice()
            .otherwise()
                .throwException(new FileNotFoundException(theFileUri))
            .endChoice();
```

There are two problems with this:

- if the file is missing, the success log still happens (but not the bean!)
- the stack trace is not printed

If there is a better way to do this then I'd welcome suggestions but I'd also like to know what I'm doing wrong in this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still not completely clear to me what is going on. However, I believe that the `onException` call needs to be separated from the chain. It looks to me that `logStackTrace` applies only to redelivery attempts. The number of attempts defaults to 0 and this is what I want. The only way to access the exception from the Java DSL appears to be a custom `Processor`. [The `getException()` method will return `null` if you are using `handled(true)` so you must use `Exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, Exception.class)`](http://camel.apache.org/why-is-the-exception-null-when-i-use-onexception.html).

I also suspect that the log message from the onCompletion is due to it [running in parallel](http://camel.apache.org/oncompletion.html) before the exception aborts:

> Camel 2.13 or older - On completion runs in separate thread Icon The
>   onCompletion runs in a separate thread in parallel with the original
>   route. It is therefore not intended to influence the outcome of the
>   original route. The idea for on completion is to spin off a new thread
>   to eg send logs to a central log database, send an email, send alterts
>   to a monitoring system, store a copy of the result message etc.
>   Therefore if you want to do some work that influence the original
>   route, then do not use onCompletion for that. Notice: if you use the
>   UnitOfWork API as mentioned in the top of this page, then you can
>   register a Synchronization callback on the Exchange which is executed
>   in the original route. That way allows you to do some custom code when
>   the route is completed; this is how custom components can enlist on
>   completion services which they need, eg the File component does that
>   for work that moves/deletes the original file etc.

Since I want to not run this code on exception, I think I can just abort the route with the exception.

I currently have this:

```
    onException(Exception.class)
        .handled(true)
        .process(new Processor()
        {
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange anExchange) throws Exception
            {
                Exception myException = anExchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, Exception.class);
                LOGGER.error("Failed to load", myException);
            }
        });
    from(theFileUri)
        .choice()
            .when(body().isNotNull())
                .to(NEXT_ROUTE_URI)
                .log("SUCCESS")
                .bean(theOtherAction, "start")
            .endChoice()
            .otherwise()
                .throwException(new FileNotFoundException(theFileUri));
```